# How to reference firebase pushId key?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have the following code and I'm trying to use the firebase key in the "upvote" function, however, It will not allow me to reference "key" in "upvote".  My question is, since the other functions such as "edit" and "async delete" are able to reference "key", where are they getting it from and how can I use it in "upvote"?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'Firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
infos = [];
  ref = firebase.database().ref('infos/').orderByChild('vote');
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router, public alertController: AlertController) {
    this.ref.on('value', resp => {
      this.infos = [];
      this.infos = snapshotToArray(resp);  
    });
}
  edit(key) {
    this.router.navigate(['/edit/'+key]);
   console.log(key); <------ Correct Key-------
  }
  async delete(key) {
  console.log(key); <------ Correct Key-------
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Confirm!',
      message: 'Are you sure want to delete this info?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: (blah) => {
            console.log('cancel');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Okay',
          handler: () => {
            firebase.database().ref('infos/'+key).remove();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();
    console.log(key);
  }
upvote(key) {
const data = { };
console.log(key);  <------ Undefined? -------
firebase.database().ref('infos/' + key +'/vote').transaction(function(value) {
  if (value) {
    value--;
  }
 return value;
});
}}
export const snapshotToArray = snapshot => {
  let returnArr = [];
  snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      let item = childSnapshot.val();
      item.key = childSnapshot.key;
      returnArr.push(item);
  });
  return returnArr;
}
```

EDIT:  solved my problem by fixing how I reference the function in the html.  I simply wasn't calling it correctly.  see below:

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let info of infos" (click)="detail(info.key)">
      <ion-item detail lines="full" >
        <ion-icon name="desktop" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        {{info.info_title}} - {{info.vote2}} - {{info.key}}
          <ion-button shape="round" color="primary" expand="block" (click)="upvote(info.key)">Upvote</ion-button>
        <ion-button shape="round" color="primary" expand="block" (click)="downvote(info.key)">Downvote</ion-button>

      </ion-item>

      <ion-item-options side="end">
        <ion-item-option color="primary" (click)="edit(info.key)">EDIT</ion-item-option>
        <ion-item-option color="danger" (click)="delete(info.key)">DELETE</ion-item-option>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
```

Before I was calling "upvote" like this :
Upvote

the result was undefined and a massive headache!

Comment: could you update the question to show where the Homepage's edit, delete and upvote methods are used? From another component

Comment: @lazreg87 you gave ma an idea and I figured it out.  I wasn't reverencing the function correctly in the html.  Once I changed that it worked perfectly!  Thank you!!

Comment: Edited question to include my fix for my use case